# Spock Stepwise - Keep running testsuite after single failure

Tags: spring, grails, spock, geb

When using the Spock @Stepwise annotation, is there any way to configure it to not fail the entire testsuite after a single test fails?

Comment: Please have a look here: https://code.google.com/p/spock/issues/detail?id=334

Comment: Thanks Opal, though from what I understand the ordering may not always be sequential in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decided to just create a new extension called @StepThrough. All I needed to do was subclass StepwiseExtension and take out the line of code that was failing the entire test suite. Pasted code below...

StepThrough.groovy

```
package com.test.SpockExtensions

import org.spockframework.runtime.extension.ExtensionAnnotation

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType
import java.lang.annotation.Retention
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy
import java.lang.annotation.Target

/**
 * Created by jchertkov on 6/22/15.
 */
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ExtensionAnnotation(StepThroughExtension.class)
public @interface StepThrough {}
```

StepThroughExtension.groovy

```
package com.test.SpockExtensions

import org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.StepwiseExtension
import org.spockframework.runtime.model.SpecInfo

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation

/**
 * Created by jchertkov on 6/22/15.
 */
public class StepThroughExtension extends StepwiseExtension {
    public void visitSpecAnnotation(Annotation annotation, final SpecInfo spec) {
        sortFeaturesInDeclarationOrder(spec);
        includeFeaturesBeforeLastIncludedFeature(spec);
    }
}
```

Notes:

- I put the code into a package called com.test.SpockExtensions. You will need to do the same with whatever name you would like.
- Java users - just change filetype from .groovy to .java

Comment: Thanks! You can also accept your own answer here in Stack Overflow.