# Class cannot resolve module as content unless @Stepwise used

Tags: testing, automation, spock, geb

I have a Spock class, that when run as a test suite, throws `Unable to resolve iconRow as content for geb.Page, or as a property on its Navigator context. Is iconRow a class you forgot to import?` unless I annotate my class with @Stepwise. However, I *really* don't want the test execution to stop on the first failure, which @Stepwise does.

I've tried writing (copy and pasting) my own extension using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30978729/3486967) post, but I still get these errors. It is using my extension, as I added some logging statements that were printed out to the console.

Here is one of my modules:

```
class IconRow extends Module {
    static content = {
        iconRow (required: false) {$("div.report-toolbar")}
    }
}
```

And a page that uses it:

```
class Report extends SomeOtherPage {
    static at = {$("div.grid-container").displayed}

    static content = {
        iconRow { module IconRow }
    }
}
```

And a snippet of the test that is failing:

```
class MyFailingTest extends GebReportingSpec {

    def setupSpec() {
        via Dashboard
        SomeClass.login("SourMonk", "myPassword")
        assert page instanceof Dashboard

        nav.goToReport("Some report name")
        assert page instanceof Report
    }

    @Unroll
    def "I work"() {
        given:
        at Report

        expect:
        this == that

        where:
        this << ["some list", "of values"]
        that << anotherModule.someContent*.@id
    }

    @Unroll
    def "I don't work"() {
        given:
        at Report

        expect:
        this == that

        where:
        this << ["some other", "list", "of values"]
        that << iconRow.columnHeaders*.attr("innerText")*.toUpperCase()
    }
}
```

When executed as a suite `I work` passes and `I don't work` fails because it cannot identify "iconRow" as content for the page. If I switch the order of the test cases, `I don't work` will pass and `I work` will fail. Alternatively, if I execute each test separately, they both pass.

What I have tried:

- Adding/removing the `required: true` property from content in the modules
- Prefixing the module name with the class, such as `IconRow.iconRow`
- Defining my modules as static `@Shared` properties
- Initialize the modules both in and outside of my `setupSpec()`
- Making simple getter methods in each module's class that return the module, and referencing content such as `IconRow.getIconRow().columnHeaders*.attr("innerText")*.toUpperCase()`
- Moving the contents of my `setupSpec()` into `setup()`
- Adding `autoClearCookies = false` into my GebConfig.groovy
- Making a `@Shared Report report` variable and prefix all modules with that such as `report.iconRow`

Very peculiar note about that last bullet point -- it magically resolves the modules that *don't* have the prefix -- so it won't resolve `report.IconRow` but will resolve just `iconRow` -- absolutely bizarre, because if I remove that variable the module that was just previously working suddenly can't be resolved again. I even tried declaring this variable and then not prefixing anything, and that did not work either.

Another problem that I keep banging my head against the wall with is that I'm also not sure of *where* the problem is. The error it throws leads me to believe that it's a project setup issue, but running each feature individually works fine, so it appears to be resolving the classes just fine.

On the other hand, perhaps it's an issue with the session and/or cookies? Although I have yet to see any official documentation on this, it seems to be the general consensus (from other posts and articles I've read) that only using `@Stepwise` will maintain your session between feature methods. If this is the case, why is my extension not working? It's pretty much a copy and paste of `@Stepwise` without the `skipFeaturesAfterFirstFailingFeature` method (I can post if needed), unless there is some other stuff going on behind the scenes with `@Stepwise`.

Apologies for the wall of text, but I've been trying to figure this out for about 6 hours now, so my brain is pretty fried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geb has special support for `@Stepwise`, if a spec is annotated with it it does not call `resetBrowser()` after each test, instead it is called after the spec is completed. See the code on [github](https://github.com/geb/geb/blob/847e69efb10182f859093763504117312a363e81/module/geb-spock/src/main/groovy/geb/spock/GebSpec.groovy#L71-L80)

So basically you need to change your `setupSpec` to `setup` so that it will be executed before each test.

Regarding your observation, if you just run a focused test the `setupSpec` is executed for that test and thus it passes. The problem arises, that the cleanup is invoked afterwards and resets the browser, breaking subsequent tests.

**EDIT**

I overlooked your usage of `where` blocks, everything in the where block needs to be statically (`@Shared`) available, so using instance level constructs won't work. Resetting the browser will also kill every reference so just getting it before wont work either. Basically, don't use Geb objects in `where` blocks!

Looking at your code however I don't see any reason to use data driven tests here.

1. This can be easily done with one assertion in a normal test
2. It is good practice for unit tests to just test one thing. Geb however, is not an unit test but an acceptance/frontend test. The problem here is that they are way slower than unit tests and it makes sense to combine sensible assertions into one test.

```
class MyFailingTest extends GebReportingSpec {    
    def setup() {
        via Dashboard
        SomeClass.login("SourMonk", "myPassword")
        assert page instanceof Dashboard

        nav.goToReport("Some report name")
        assert page instanceof Report
    }

    def "I work"() {
        given:
        at Report

        expect:
        ["some list", "of values"] == anotherModule.someContent*.@id
    }

    def "I don't work"() {
        given:
        at Report

        expect:
        ["some other", "list", "of values"] == iconRow.columnHeaders*.attr("innerText")*.toUpperCase()
    }
}
```

Comment: So I've tried moving the contents of my setupSpec() to just setup() and the tests are still failing with the same error. Is there anyway to override those methods in GebSpec?

Comment: Thanks, Leonard that is working for me -- I guess I had a simple misunderstanding of the framework. So what is it that allows for Geb objects to be accessed in 'expect' but not 'where'?

Comment: @SourMonk `where` is "executed" before the actual tests run since it provides that input data for the tests, this is normally not an issue except for some edge cases where non-static data is used. `expect` is part of the test itself. Maybe the image here helps to understand it better http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#_blocks