# Why any Geb page method or module method can not be accessed in Where block

Tags: spock, geb

I have a Page class and having some method which extract the Web page. Now I want to call these method into the Where block of Spock to pass as data provider. But when I call the method then it throws an error as it did not find it. But the same is accessible from out of Where block. Why is it so?

*Example*

```
def "Validate all article has its id"(){
    when:"I am at Overview page"
    at OverviewPage

    then:"I should the article id of all article"
    getAllCountOf(articleInfo).size() ==  actualCount

    where:
    articleInfo                          |actualCount
    TopArticleListInfo.ARTICLE_THUMBNAIL |filter.getCount()
```

}

In the above code 'filter.getCount()' can not be accessed from Where block, But the same method is accessible in when or then block.

i want to understand the logic behind the scene It looks like , Where block is not able to find this method statically, need to create an object to call this.

When I tried the solution provided by erdi, But that also not solving the issue

```
when:"I am at Overview page"
    at OverviewPage
    then:"I should the article id of all article"
    getAllCountOf(articleInfo).size() ==  page."$actualCount"

    where:
    articleInfo                          |actualCount
    TopArticleListInfo.ARTICLE_THUMBNAIL |'getRowCount().size()'
```

Here getRowCount().size() substitute in "$actualCount". But still it throwing the error

### Error Message

getAllCountOf(articleInfo).size() ==  page."$actualCount"
    |             |            |          |    |
    |             |            10         |    groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Unable to resolve getRowCount().size() as content for inca.sundashboard.pageobject.OverviewPage, or as a property on its Navigator context. Is getRowCount().size() a class you forgot to import?
    |

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Spock Data Tables to Test Geb Page Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46960922/using-spock-data-tables-to-test-geb-page-objects)

Comment: See my response to the question Leonard mentioned for explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46971915/1856764

Comment: I tried the solution provided by you , But it did not resolve the issue i am facing.       
    when:"I am at Overview page"
        at OverviewPage
        then:"I should the article id of all article"
        getAllCountOf(articleInfo).size() ==  page."$actualCount"

        where:
        articleInfo                          |actualCount
        TopArticleListInfo.ARTICLE_THUMBNAIL |'getRowCount().size()' .   this piece of code does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using [Dynamic Method Names](http://www.groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_dynamic_method_names) in my tests, here is a small example:

```
def "Validate all article has its id"(){
    when: "I am at Overview page"
    at OverviewPage

    then: "I should the article id of all article"
    getAllCountOf(articleInfo).size() ==  "$actualCountMethod"().getCount()

    where:
    articleInfo                          | actualCountMethod
    TopArticleListInfo.ARTICLE_THUMBNAIL | filter
```

}

Comment: This really worked out. This is what i was looking for to pass the dynamic method from data table. Thank you so much @Royg for your help.